# Word/phrase for non-human agent

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do we call a non-human (virtual) agent in computer science domain? I'm looking for a word/phrase other than bot or artificial agent.

[image: Non-human agent]

Comment: Do you need a general term or can you just give your bot an actual name? "Look it up using Sinclair."

Comment: "Bot" *is* a word. It also means exactly that. It is also universally used. What am I missing?

Comment: @Catija, I'm looking for a general term to describe it.

Comment: Also, why not "virtual agent" ? It is used in [computer science](https://www.google.ca/search?q=robagent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iLtxVayBKoz9yQS2rIOoAg#safe=off&tbm=bks&q=%22virtual-agent%22).

Comment: @ermanen, Agreed, just edited.

Comment: Can you explain **how** you want to use it that shows why "bot", for example, is not usable for you?

Comment: @Mrstupid, AI is a general concept and most of non-human agents are developed based on that.

Comment: @Eilia this is the reason I deleted my post. Have a look at my answer. maybe something useful there.

Comment: In fact, most of time (if not always) such agents are only _programmed scripts_ . In this regard, I think calling them *bot* may be misleading for some people. They may think we are talking about **robots** or **androids**.

Comment: Nobody is mislead.  it would be like not knowing exactly what "email" is.  Everyone has the sense of a chatbot, indeed "bot" often very specifically implies "software agent" as opposed to an actual metal robot.

Comment: In multiplayer games, these are NPCs.  Non-player characters.  But I'm with @JoeBlow-- "bot" is not misleading.

Comment: A human simulation or just a simulation

Answer (score 1):

Try **intelligent virtual agent, virtual rep** or **v-rep**

The site reads:

> ....In customer relationship management (CRM), a virtual agent (sometimes called an intelligent virtual agent, virtual rep or v-rep).....

Source:
[Virtual Agent](http://searchcrm.techtarget.com/definition/virtual-agent)